# Equation numbers do not align to rightmost in beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, align

I have the following code in `\documentclass{beamer}`,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \texttt{align} environment:
  \begin{align}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x\\y\\z
  \end{bmatrix}&=
                 \begin{bmatrix}
                   1&&\\&2&\\&&3
                 \end{bmatrix}
                 \begin{bmatrix}
                   1\\2\\3
                 \end{bmatrix} \\
  &=
  \label{eq:4}
                 \begin{bmatrix}
                   1&&\\&2&\\&&3
                 \end{bmatrix}
                 \begin{bmatrix}
                   d\\e\\f
                 \end{bmatrix}\\
  \label{eq:1}
  a&=b
\end{align}
\texttt{equation} environment:
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:5}
  a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following slide.

[image]

And we can see that the last equation number does not line up. I did not have such a problem if I used `\documentclass{article}` instead.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

Comment: If you add `\tag{a\rlap{\smash{\rule[-10cm]{0.4pt}{12cm}}}}` to the first row in the align, the problem is easily seen.

Comment: Theory: in beamer, perhaps `equation` is redefined to be `gather`, because `gather` shows the same problem. Might want to add gather as an example as well.

Comment: Further experiment, it is something inside the beamer frame env, if you redefine `frame` to do nothing (`\renewenvironment`) then the placement is correct. We probably need some of the `beamer` people to have a look at this.

Comment: @daleif I noticed just now that not only the label, the two matrices does not align either. btw, glad to know the trick to show this.

Comment: Yes, now you mention it. I'm currently updating my TeXLive to see if there are any updates that I have missed. The (r/l)lap+smash+rule trick is rather useful.

Comment: Have you checked to see if it is `\label` that does something it should not? Just checked, `\label` seems to leave a space behind.

Comment: It seems that it is the `\label` what moves everything. Out comment all `\labels`, and it looks like it should.

Comment: @daleif, OH, I think it IS `\label` after some checking!

Comment: Hmm, I think that is a feature, not a bug. You should not place `eq:4` there, move it to be the first on the row, then everything is ok again

Comment: the `\label` probably leaves a "whatsit", which `=` and the matrix reacts to and this creates an extra small space. I'll add that as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a bit of messing around, the issue seems to be a bad `\label` placement.

```
               \end{bmatrix} \\
&=
\label{eq:4} %<----
             \begin{bmatrix}
```

Note that the marked label is after `&=`, the whatsit probably ends up confusing the math spacing. Moving the `\label` up as the first thing on this line, removes the problem.

The solution is to start or end the row with `\label`, don't add it the middle of the formula. For the sniplet above use

```
               \end{bmatrix} \\
\label{eq:4} %<----
&=
             \begin{bmatrix}
```

I have no idea why this causes the equation numbers to be placed misaligned.

Comment: excuse me, could you pls provide a complete code sample so that I can test it?  currently any `\label` inside `align` will mess up the alignment for me. thanks~

Comment: Oh, I had to put `\label{eq:4}` above `&=` to make everything (matrices + equation numbers) align

Comment: Thanks, I see where I did wrong in my original code. Another questions is that if I add a `\label{eq:xx}` above the first equations (below `\begin{align}`), the misalignment reappears. This time it's just the numbering, not the matrices. How can I fix that?

Comment: @davyjones Please post it as a new question. Then we need the `beamer` maintainers to look at it.

Comment: sure, I'll try it out and post it soon. I think this new question is the real question I originally want to ask. I'll do it more carefully next time. Thanks!

Comment: @davyjones might even be an idea to make the MWE have two aligns and an equation, then only add `\label` to one of the aligns. My guess is that there is a sporadic space somewhere on the code.

Comment: @davyjones seems `{\label{...}}` helps...

Comment: [whatsits](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whatsit#Noun)

Comment: I think the problem is caused by the `bmatrix` environment and not the `\label` and `align`! (Try the code without `bmatrix`.)

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is caused by the `bmatrix` environment. Use `{\begin{bmatrix}...\end{bmatrix}}`! Try this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \texttt{align} environment:
\begin{align}
  {\begin{bmatrix}
    x\\y\\z
  \end{bmatrix}}&=
                 {\begin{bmatrix}
                   1&&\\&2&\\&&3
                 \end{bmatrix}}
                 {\begin{bmatrix}
                   1\\2\\3
                 \end{bmatrix}}\label{eq:1}\\
  &=
                 {\begin{bmatrix}
                   1&&\\&2&\\&&3
                 \end{bmatrix}}
                 {\begin{bmatrix}
                   d\\e\\f
                 \end{bmatrix}}\label{eq:2}\\
  a&=b\label{eq:3}
\end{align}
\texttt{equation} environment:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:4}
  a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, I saw something similar in the chatroom, this is really a unconventional strike for `bmatrix` fans. I'll post another question to attract `beamer` maintainers' attention as suggested.