# Misalignment of equation numbers in beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, align, matrices

As is suggested by @daleif, this is a related question of the my previous [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409449/37198), now I have the following code in `beamer`,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \texttt{align} environment:
  \begin{align}
    \label{eq:1}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      x\\y\\z
    \end{bmatrix}&=
                 \begin{bmatrix}
                   1&&\\&2&\\&&3
                 \end{bmatrix}
                 \begin{bmatrix}
                   1\\2\\3
                 \end{bmatrix} \\
    \label{eq:2}
                 &=
                   \begin{bmatrix}
                     1&&\\&2&\\&&3
                   \end{bmatrix}
                   \begin{bmatrix}
                     d\\e\\f
                   \end{bmatrix}\\
    \label{eq:3}
    a&=b
  \end{align}
  \texttt{equation} environment:
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:4}
    a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}
  \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which will produce the following slide,
[image]
where we can see that the misalignment of the equation numbers.

As is sugessted by @daleif in the comments of his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409453/37198), change `\label{eq:1}` to `{\label{eq:1}}` would help.

It is also [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409463/37198) that wrap `{}` around `bmatrix` environment would also help.

Also just to mention my original cumbersome solution, which is to add `&&` before (and possibly after) each line to fake it as multiple alignment, then the numbers would also line up.

Surely for now `{\label{eq:1}}` is the simplest solutions, but why is this happening, and is there a more "standard" way to handle this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The problem

The problem is actually not restricted to the `bmatrix` environment, as can be seen from the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{showframe} %% <- make the text area visible

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{align}
        \label{eq:1}
        A                             %% <- This is fine
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        \label{eq:2}
        \left(A\right)                %% <- Not fine
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        \label{eq:3}
        -A                            %% <- Not fine
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        \label{eq:4}
        \begin{bmatrix}A\end{bmatrix} %% <- Not fine
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        \begin{bmatrix}A\end{bmatrix} %% <- This is fine
    \end{align}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: bad output]

This occurs due to the fact that `beamer` modifies `\label` and that the modified command creates an `\hbox`.
This `\hbox` itself takes up no space, but since it is part of the equation it can cause horizontal skips to be inserted when it is followed or preceded by particular types of objects.
This for instance happens if it is preceded/followed by a binary operator (like `+` or `-`), a binary relation (like `=` or `<`), an operator like (`\sin` or `\sum`) OR an "inner atom" like `\left[` and `\right]`.
(I'm not going to list all possibilities, but see the table in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81777/156366).)

In your case, a `\thinmuskip` (as produced by `\,`) is inserted between this `\hbox` and the `\left[` at the start of a `bmatrix`.
In the `-A` example above, a `\medmuskip` (as produced by `\:`) is inserted before the `-` and *another* `\medmuskip` is inserted after it because this operator is now interpreted as a binary operator!

The reason why this messes up the placement of the equation label is that `align` typesets its contents twice: once to measure its size and once for real.
During the "measuring phase", `\label` is redefined to do nothing, which in particular means that it will not insert the aforementioned `\hbox` when it is just being measured.
Consequently, `amsmath` ends up measuring the width of the cell incorrectly and using this incorrect value to determine how much space should be inserted before/after/between columns.

---

## Solutions

#### (1) Manual solution

Using `{\label{<name>}}` (or e.g. `\label{<name>}{}` or `\label{<name>}\hbox{}`) only partially solves this problem.
If this is used, `amsmath` will still see an empty group (`{}`) during the measuring phase, which is the same as a `\hbox{…}` and `{\hbox{…}}` for spacing purposes.
It thus fixes the placement of the equation number by introducing the same unnecessary skip during the measuring phase.
(Also: the space between `-` and `A` in the third equation above will still be wrong!)

If you want to solve this without hacking `beamer`'s redefinition of `\label`, you can replace `\label{<name>}` by `\mathopen{\label{<name>}}` if used at the start of a cell.
This works because no space is ever inserted after an Open atom.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{showframe} %% <- make the text area visible

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{align}
        \label{eq:1}
        A                             %% <- Still fine
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        \mathopen{\label{eq:2}}
        \left(A\right)                %% <- Now fine!
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        \mathopen{\label{eq:3}}
        -A                            %% <- Now fine!
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        \mathopen{\label{eq:4}}
        \begin{bmatrix}A\end{bmatrix} %% <- Now fine!
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        \begin{bmatrix}A\end{bmatrix} %% <- Still fine
    \end{align}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: good output]

(Note that also `-A` is now also spaced correctly!)

(*Replacing `\label{<name>}` by `\mathclose{\label{<name>}}` at the end of a cell usually works, but not quite always: a skip will still be inserted if the label is preceded by punctuation (like a `,`).*)

#### (2) Patching `beamer`

You can also patch `beamer` to make sure that no `\hbox` is ever inserted in the first place.
The offending `\hbox` can be found here (in `beamerbasenavigation.sty`):

```
\def\beamer@inserttarget#1{%
  \ifbeamer@inframe%
    \ifvmode%
      \nointerlineskip\vbox to0pt{#1}%
    \else%
      \hbox{#1}% %% <- This is the problem!
    \fi%
  \else% defer to next frame
    \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\beamer@framehypertargets\expandafter{\beamer@framehypertargets#1}%
  \fi%
}
```

*(`#1` is of the form `\hypertarget{<label name>}{}` and it sets up the target for hyperlinks pointing to this equation.)*

The problem is solved if this line is removed, but we don't want to do that since that'd destroy hyperlinks.
It would also be solved if `\hbox{#1}` is replaced by `#1`, but we don't want to do that either since that `\hbox` is probably there for a reason (which probably does not apply in math mode).

So here is a proposal: if you add the following to your preamble, `#1` will be inserted directly in math mode, and it will be `\hbox`ed when used elsewhere.

```
\makeatletter %% <- make @ usable in command names
  \patchcmd{\beamer@inserttarget}
    {\hbox{#1}}{\ifmmode#1\else\hbox{#1}\fi}{}{}
\makeatother  %% <- revert @
```

(*`\patchcmd` is part of the [`etoolbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package, which is already loaded by `beamer`.*)

Here is the result:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{showframe} %% <- make the text area visible

\makeatletter %% <- make @ usable in command names
  \patchcmd{\beamer@inserttarget}
    {\hbox{#1}}{\ifmmode#1\else\hbox{#1}\fi}{}{}
\makeatother  %% <- revert @

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{align}
        \label{eq:1}
        A                             %% <- Still fine
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        \label{eq:2}
        \left(A\right)                %% <- Also fine!
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        \label{eq:3}
        -A                            %% <- Also fine!
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        \label{eq:4}
        \begin{bmatrix}A\end{bmatrix} %% <- Also fine!
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        \begin{bmatrix}A\end{bmatrix} %% <- Still fine
    \end{align}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    The hyperlinks in the references \ref{eq:1} and \ref{eq:4} still work.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: good output]

Comment: @samcarter: Writing short answers is something I seem to be incapable of, but you're welcome :). This problem seemed to make no sense at first, so I just had to find out what was going on.

Comment: But the solution looked so good :( Anyway thanks for diagnosing the problem, maybe it will help some other users

Comment: @samcarter: There was a problem with the earlier version, but I think the current version should work correctly.

Comment: Good to hear! Thanks again for your answer! (awarding the bounty won't be possible until tomorrow)

Comment: @davyjones: This question is probably no longer relevant to you since it is nearly a year old, but I thought I'd mention that I've added a solution that doesn't involve hacking `beamer`.

Comment: @samcarter: I also don't know if you care about the answer (or just thought this question deserved one), but ↑↑.

Comment: Oh, this is really interesting! I admit that I started the bounty because I thought that probably more people have this problem and it would be good to have an answer, but after your detailed answer I think this is really an interesting problem. I wonder if opening an issue at https://github.com/josephwright/beamer would make sense.

Comment: @samcarter: I think it would, since this is clearly not intended and labels in equations are not uncommon. There is actually another similar incompatibility between `beamer` and `amsmath` involving `\label`s: while `\label<…>{…}` creates working labels in `align` (and correct hyperlinks), it completely destroys the spacing in the equation because `amsmath` just calls `\let\label\@gobble` when performing its measurements.

Comment: Do you have a github account to open an issue there?

Comment: @samcarter I have a (dormant) account, so I can open an issue (later).

Comment: @samcarter: I've opened an issue on the `beamer` github page: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/523